# Why am I unable to save my Tableau Dashboard to the Tableau Server?

Tags: tableau-api

I made a Tableau dashboard and now I want to save it to Tableau public.

However, I get the following error when I try to save it to Tableau public:

`Unable to complete action An unexpected error occurred saving the packaged workbook. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`

I have tried restarting my computer and opening only the Tableau workbook with the dashboard. However, I still get the above error when I try to save it to Tableau public.

Comment: publishing a dashboard to Tableau Public using Tableau Desktop requires an extract of the data involved... I just want to check if you have already done that step

Comment: Hi @FabioFantoni, I may not have done that. What do you mean an "extract" of the data? The dashboard is connected to a file on my computer. It's in the file path Tableau Prep Repositroy/Data Sources.

Edit: the filename also has an 'extract' extension

Comment: right click on your data source and choose Extract. https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/extracting_data.htm

Comment: I've just added the answer according to my first comment... feel free to accept in order to "close" this thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Tableau Desktop and you want to publish your dashboard on Tableau Public just ensure to have an extract of your datasource.

To do so, in your datasource pane right click your source and click extract.